res.setHeader is not a function occurs when logging in to nestjs+graphql+Google
I am testing Google social login with nestjs and graphql.
However, an error res.setHeader is not a function appears.

This is the auth.module.ts file.

import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AuthResolver } from './auth.resolver';
import { AuthService } from './auth.service';

import { JwtModule } from '@nestjs/jwt';
import { UsersModule } from '../users/users.module';
import { JwtAccessStrategies } from './strategies/jwt-access.strategy';
import { JwtRefreshStrategies } from './strategies/jwt-refresh.strategy';
import { JwtGoogleStrategy } from './strategies/jwt-social-google.strategy';

@Module({
  imports: [
    JwtModule.register({}), //
    UsersModule,
  ],

  providers: [
    JwtAccessStrategies,
    JwtRefreshStrategies,
    JwtGoogleStrategy,
    AuthResolver, //
    AuthService,
  ],
})
export class AuthModule {}



Next is JwtGoogleStrategy.

import { UnauthorizedException } from '@nestjs/common';
import { PassportStrategy } from '@nestjs/passport';
import { Profile, Strategy, VerifyCallback } from 'passport-google-oauth20';

export class JwtGoogleStrategy extends PassportStrategy(Strategy, 'google') {
  constructor() {
    super({
      clientID: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
      clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
      callbackURL: 'http://localhost:3001/login',
      scope: ['email', 'profile'],
    });
  }

  validate(accessToken: string, profile: Profile, done: VerifyCallback) {
    console.log('profile:', profile);

    if (!profile) {
      return done(new UnauthorizedException(), false);
    }
    return done(null, profile);
  }
}



And this is the GraphQL guard settings.

import { ExecutionContext } from '@nestjs/common';
import { GqlExecutionContext } from '@nestjs/graphql';
import { AuthGuard } from '@nestjs/passport';

export const GqlAuthGuard = (name: string) => {
  return class GqlAuthGuard extends AuthGuard(name) {
    getRequest(context: ExecutionContext) {
      const gqlContext = GqlExecutionContext.create(context);

      return gqlContext.getContext().req;
    }
  };
};



Lastly is the auth.resolver.ts file.

  @UseGuards(GqlAuthGuard('google'))
  @Mutation(() => String)
  loginGoogle(
    @Context() context: IContext, 
  ): void {
    console.log('context::', context);
    // this.authService.loginGoogle({ context });
  }


I don't know why the error occurs.
The test environment was tested using the following code in React.
  const [loginGoogle, { loading, error }] = useMutation(GOOGLE_LOGIN_MUTATION);
  const handleGoogleLogin = async () => {
    try {
      const result = await loginGoogle();
      console.log(result.data);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('뮤테이션 실행 중 에러:', error);
    }
  };


<button onClick={handleGoogleLogin}>google login</button>
...

I am testing Google social login with nestjs and graphql.
However, an error res.setHeader is not a function appears.
